# Connections to socket with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, net-snmp

I need to create Nodejs aplication that will connect to several devices using net-snmp, just one server connecting to 300 devices.
But i don't know if is a good idea to use NodeJS.

I started using NodeJS a short time ago.

Comment: Why not? Try and let us know :)

Answer (score -2):

From the [documentary](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/TUT:Simple_Application) i dont think that should be done with NodeJS since its said on the [Agent Architechture](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/Agent_Architecture)

> It usually interacts with libraries, the network, plugins, other
> processes, the file system, the local OS, and the local OS's kernel.